# Escape from Recursion with a Time Limit

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a program to play checkers where each move is timed. I am using alpha-beta pruning to find the best move. I can only go so deep in the decision tree because:

1. The decision tree is huge for checkers
2. There is a time limit I have to decide the move

Is there a way to escape from the call stack instantly when I have run out of time, even when there are lots of frames on the stack?  I thought about throwing an exception, but that seemed like a poor decision.

This is what I am doing now, but it is not fast enough

```
public Board play(Board board) {
    ArrayList<Board> actions = board.findPossibleMoves();

    if (actions.size() == 0) {
        return new Board();
    } 

    int depth = 3;
    // Each move has 1 second (1000ms)
    TimeLimit tl = new TimeLimit(1000);
    double alpha = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    double beta = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    Board bestSoFar = actions.get(0);

    double v = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (Board b : actions) {
        if (tl.isTimeUp())
          return bestSoFar;

        double result = minValue(b, depth, alpha, beta, tl);
        if (result >= v) {
            bestSoFar = b;
            v = result;
        }
        if (v >= beta) return b;
        alpha = Math.max(alpha, v);
    }
    return bestSoFar;
}

private double maxValue(Board board, int depth, double alpha, double beta, TimeLimit tl) {
    if (tl.isTimeUp())
        return score(board);
    ...
}

private double minValue(Board board, int depth, double alpha, double beta, TimeLimit tl) {
    if (tl.isTimeUp())
        return score(board);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What loop are you trying to restrict?  The for loop in the Constructor?

Comment: I'm assuming the most intensive/time consuming part is in the maxValue/minValue segments? I see you are restricting execution time for the maxValue() and minValue() methods but not for the for loop up top. Is this what you are intending to do? In other words, are you trying to restrict the execution time for maxValue()/minValue() only or for the whole Play() method?

Comment: @CPUTerminator I need to restrict execution time for the whole play() method.  I have 1 second from the time that play() is called.

Comment: @MystikSpiral I need to restrict execution time for the whole play() method. I have 1 second from the time that play() is called.

Comment: Well... What code takes the longest to execute? Do the minValue()/maxValue() block at all? You need to add a if (tl.isTimeUp()){ //code here... }else{ return bestSoFar; } to your for loop.

Comment: @CPUTerminator Yeah, the `if (tl.isTimeUp()){ return bestSoFar }` in the `for loop` would help, but if there are a lot of frames on the call stack, is it possible to return to the one on the bottom when time runs out in the one on the top?

Comment: If you want a immediate response, I recommend having the whole move calculation mechanism put in another thread posting its results to a specific object as it works. Another thread (with the one second timer) can go about and obtain the result over exactly one second. The calculation thread can then be informed to end in which it can do in whatever way it pleases (in terms of time) as the 'result' has already been obtained.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37416/discussion-between-fvrghl-and-cpu-terminator)

Comment: Why would throwing an exception be a "poor decision"? In such a case it sounds like exactly the right decision.

Comment: @user4815162342 it seemed like bad style to throw an exception as this use case isn't really what an exception is meant to be used for; running out of time sometimes is expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, but quick unwinding from the stack of unknown depth *is* a use case for exceptions. Some exceptions are expected - look up "business exceptions" - and running out of time can legitimately be one of them. (*Gratuitous* use of business exceptions is often frowned upon, but given the requirement of unwinding from deep stack, your use is not gratuitous.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that recursion is to be used in a strictly timed environment, there are several options that can be considered. These are listed below:

**OPTION 1:**

Add more if statements throughout the method body especially before segments of code that can block to ensure the code execution gets halted as soon as the time expires. A specific cushion interval must be implemented to give time for the return statements to propagate back up the stack.

**Pros:**

- Simple to implement.
- Relatively simple and effective.

**Cons:**

- Degrades readability of code.
- Does not guarantee execution will fall under specified time.

**OPTION 2:**

Port the executive code to a secondary thread which progressively writes to an object as it executes. The primary thread can then start a timer while firing off this thread. When the timer expires the primary thread need only retrieve this object and inform the worker thread to die.

**Pros:**

- Extremely accurate (results retrieved nearly on the dot with delays due to synchronization)
- Does not need a cushion interval - The recursive function can go as deep as it wants without being tied back by trying to fit the return propagation within the timer.
- Allows graceful shutdown of the executive code as it is no longer bounded by time (results are taken and the thread is allowed to die at its own pace).

**Cons:**

- Multi-threaded - Due to this solution being multi-threaded, it may not be applicable to every scenario.
- Requires a lot of extra code and possibly changes in some existing code to implement.

Comment: I would tend to agree this is a good answer except I would make the secondary thread continue to expand the tree during the other players move. Unless of course that is against the rules of the situation. Most systems are Multi-core nowadays, so it shouldn't affect performance of other code or a user interface. Of course this is harder to implement, but should result in processing as much as possible. It may help to convert the algorithm to an iterative approach as well, I've found this is often faster. You will also find other performance tips around for java usually related to android code.

Comment: @user1855149 The whole point of the time limit in this case is to stop the tree from expanding. Besides, once the move has been made it is up to the human player to make the other move, which then invalidates all previous calculations done. The OP told me he/she cannot accept a multi-threaded solution for whatever reason, thats why I included 'may not be applicable to every scenario'.